# Css spinning word effect

Tags: html, css

Please, could someone help me accomplish the letter spinning effect on hover on this [site](https://filippobello.com/)? I managed to spin letters individually, but I'd like the whole word to flip with some delay among letters.

I've mostly followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uOq_mBZ6Xw). My code looks like this:

```
{/* html */}
<h1 className={styles.title}>
      <div className={styles.letter_container}>
        <span className={styles.letter}>s</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>o</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>n</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>g</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.letter_container}>
        <span className={styles.letter}>o</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>f</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.letter_container}>
        <span className={styles.letter}>t</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>h</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>e</span>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.letter_container}>
        <span className={styles.letter}>d</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>a</span>
        <span className={styles.letter}>y</span>
      </div>
    </h1>



    /* css */
    .letter_container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .letter {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .letter_container span:hover {
      animation: spin 1s infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? Some basic code snippet or something. It would be helpful for us to help you out.

Comment: Since you have a working example on that website. I would advice you to look through the source code and find out how they did it. If I would help you that would be the way I would do it. But then it's better that you do it yourself so you can learn from the investigation.

Comment: can you share the SS of what exactly you want to do? check this out so far what I have understood is you want to have something like this? https://www.bypeople.com/3d-carousel-pure-css/

Comment: @DennizVDraanen I've been doing this for almost 2 days. You are absolutely right. But I lost patience after not getting what I wanted :).

Comment: @MilanSachani What I want is the spinning words while hovering and not the carousel. But nice tip you gave me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure, but if you'd like to spin the letters individually with delays between them like in the site, you could just add classes to the letters and make the whole animation start if they hover over the word.

```
.letter-1 {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.letter-2 {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

or just add delays in-line `style="--delay: 0.1s;"` which is what they used in the website. I haven't looked into it too much so try inspecting the website's elements.

Extra CSS animation libraries if you still need them: [Animate.css](https://animate.style/), [Animista](https://animista.net)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try doing the second suggestion as soon as possible. Your first suggestion didn't work, though.

Comment: That's odd, though I should probably look into it more.

Comment: The letters kept spinning individually on hover. I'd like them to spin with delay while hovering the word (just like that site) not the letter. Thank you for your help!